# {puppetserver ca list --all} default host name and output format

Tags: puppet

While migrating from puppet 5 to 6 (6.20), it was noticed that `puppet cert ca list --all`  was deprecated with `puppetserver ca list --all`.  When we execute this command we get an error:

> Fatal error when running action 'list'   Error: Failed connecting to
> https://puppet:8140/puppet-ca/v1/certificate_statuses/any_key   Root
> cause: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name
> or service not known)

This error indicates that puppet is looking for a host names puppet whereas the puppetserver host alias in /etc/hosts is puppetserver.
When we add another alias as puppet to /etc/hosts then this command gets executed successfully. I have 2 queries on this

1. Is there a mechanism to execute this command without modifying /etc/hosts
2. What is the output structure of this command. I need to parse this using a script. In version 5 the format was having a prefix of +, - etc, which does not exists now.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning 1-st question.

Now days it's due to default hard-coded or configured hostname under the hood.
Name may be defined in `puppet.conf` and no need to support `/etc/hosts`

```
[server]
server = fqdn.fqdn
```

or

```
[server]
ca_server = fqdn.fqdn
```

As described in configuration manual at https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/configuration.html#ca-server

> ca_server
> The server to use for certificate authority requests. It's a separate server because it cannot and does not need to horizontally scale.
>
> Default: $server

However there is life hack:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts | grep puppet
127.0.0.1 puppetmaster puppet
```

And `puppetserver ca` will succeed too in certain cases.